# Convert Arabic string to Unicode

Tags: java, android

I have a string like this:

```
"مرحبا هذا نص تجريبي"
```

And, I want to convert it to something like this:

```
"\u0623\u0646\u0627"
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way. --- [Why is “Is there a way to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can e.g. do it like this:

```java
String input = "مرحبا هذا نص تجريبي";

StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    char ch = input.charAt(i);
    if (ch >= 32 && ch < 127)
        buf.append(ch);
    else
        buf.append(String.format("\\u%04x", (int) ch));
}
String result = buf.toString();

System.out.println(result);
```

*Output*

```
\u0645\u0631\u062d\u0628\u0627 \u0647\u0630\u0627 \u0646\u0635 \u062a\u062c\u0631\u064a\u0628\u064a
```

Comment: It works, thank you. But when I send an SMS using this form it doesn't receive in Arabic words, it is being sent as a normal text.

Comment: @IlyasseSalama Can't help with that, since you don't say which SMS API you're using, and don't show any code using it, so we can't help you figure out what you might have done wrong. This question has been answered. If you want help with the API itself, create a new question and include the relevant information.

Comment: Thanks, solved by adding "encoding=UCS2" to my request

Comment: @IlyasseSalama So UTF-16, not UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

A possibly-pedantic footnote. In Java,

"مرحبا هذا نص تجريبي"

is **already** Unicode. Because Strings are Unicode in Java.  What you want is generally referred to as "escaping" the string -- representing characters by sequences of other characters.

The answer from @Andreas is good for how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with JavaMail, but it did not require me escaping characters. All I had to do was add one line of code:

```
MimeUtility.encodeText(fileName)
```

Comment: I'm trying to send an SMS through API, but it sends like this "??? ???? ??" Is there any solution for that?

Comment: @IlyasseSalama have you tried to use &type=unicode in your POST command?

Comment: Thank you, solved by adding "encoding=UCS2"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andreas,
It works, For my case under SOAPUI, I created a script that is using this code as a defined function that I call whenever I need.

Very helpuful:

```
def convertToUnicode (inputString){
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder()
for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
    char ch = inputString.charAt(i)
    if (ch >= 32 && ch < 127)
        buf.append(ch)
    else
        buf.append(String.format("\\u%04x", (int) ch));
}
String result = buf.toString()
return result
}
```